# Delete ALL httpClient Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I want to delete all tasks from array with `httpClient`.

```
clearTasks():Observable[] {
        return this.httpClient.delete<Task[]>(this.apiUrl);
      }
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
clearTasks():Observable<Task[]> {
    return this.httpClient.delete<Task[]>(this.apiUrl);
}
```

Comment: removeTasks() {
    this.taskService.clearTasks().subscribe(() => this.todos = []);
  }
and i have 404 error.Why ?  this.apiUrl is correct